# Optimize SQL query (Facebook-like application)

Tags: mysql, optimization

My application is similar to Facebook, and I'm trying to optimize the query that get user records. The user records are that he as src ou dst. The `src` is in `usermuralentry` directly, the `dst` list are in `usermuralentry_user`.

So, a entry can have one `src` and many `dst`.

I have those tables:

```
mysql> desc usermuralentry ;
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field           | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id              | int(11)          | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_src_id     | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| private         | tinyint(1)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| content         | longtext         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| date            | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| last_update     | datetime         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
10 rows in set (0.10 sec)


mysql> desc usermuralentry_user ;
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| usermuralentry_id | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| userinfo_id       | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

And the following query to retrieve information from two users.

```
mysql> explain

SELECT *
FROM usermuralentry AS a
   , usermuralentry_user AS b
WHERE a.user_src_id IN ( 1, 2 )
   OR
   (
      a.id = b.usermuralentry_id
         AND b.userinfo_id IN ( 1, 2 )
   );
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type | possible_keys                                                                             | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                                          |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | b     | ALL  | usermuralentry_id,usermuralentry_user_bcd7114e,usermuralentry_user_6b192ca7 | NULL | NULL    | NULL |  147188 |                                                |
|  1 | SIMPLE      | a     | ALL  | PRIMARY                                                                                   | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 1371289 | Range checked for each record (index map: 0x1) |
+----+-------------+-------+------+-------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+---------+------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

but it is taking A LOT of time...

Some tips to optimize? Can the table schema be better in my application?

Comment: What does "The user records are that he as src ou dst." mean?

Comment: A entry can have one src and many dst, and they are all users. When i go to user page, i want to see every entry he is src and dst.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use this query

```
SELECT *
FROM usermuralentry AS a
left join usermuralentry_user AS b
on b.usermuralentry_id = a.id
WHERE a.user_src_id IN(1, 2)
OR (a.id = b.usermuralentry_id
AND b.userinfo_id IN(1, 2));
```

And for some tips here are
You are using two tables in from clause which is a cartision product and will take a lot of time as well as undesired results. Always use joins in this situation.

Answer (score 1):

I think your join isn't properly formed, and you need to change the query to use UNION.  The OR condition in the where clause is killing performance as well:

```
SELECT *
FROM usermuralentry AS a
 JOIN usermuralentry_user AS b ON a.id = b.usermuralentry_id /* use explicit JOIN! */
WHERE a.user_src_id IN (1 , 2)
 UNION
SELECT *
FROM usermuralentry AS a
 JOIN usermuralentry_user AS b ON a.id = b.usermuralentry_id 
WHERE b.usermuralentry_id IN ( 1, 2 )
```

You also need an index: ALTER TABLE usermuralentry_user ADD INDEX (usermuralentry_id)